# How to exit full screen mode in AVPlayerViewController in iOS9

Tags: swift, ios9, avplayer, ios9.1, avplayerviewcontroller

I am woking on `iOS` app. I need to play video in `Portrait` and `Landscape` mode. I have implemented `AVPlayerViewController` to play video.

I have implemented video is finish then pop to previous screen. Every things is working fine but When user play video in `Portrait` mode and click on full screen button and player enter full screen mode but video end then player screen not to pop and Done button is not work.

How to fixed this problem ?

Comment: Same problem here!

Comment: Have you ever found a solution around this?